# Llamada a dependencia maven con scope provided

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, dependencias

Tengo un módulo Maven que llama a una dependencia que yo mismo me construí, todo funciona bien cuando tiene el scope: compile , pero cuando cambio de scope a: provided me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/domolin/process/view/ProcessManagementView (Module "deployment.ProcessManagement.war" from Service Module Loader): com/domolin/defintion/bean/AdminBean
```

Mi pregunta es como llamo a mi dependencia con scope provided para que compile.

Adjunto mi clase Padre que se encuentra en un modulo maven(jar)
[image: Aqui heredo de AdminBean]

Clase padre:
[image: Clase padre]

Dependencias:

Archivo pom:
[image: Cambio a provided y deja de compilar mi proyecto war.]

Estare muy agradecido de que me puedan colaborar, ya voy tres dias con este problema y no encuentro solucion.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Es un error de ejecución o de compilación? ¿cómo ejecutas el programa? ¿puedes mostrar el mensaje de error?. Tienes el botón "Editar" para modificar la respuesta. Además, el código relevante debe ir como texto, no como imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes llamar a tu dependencia(jar) con la siguiente configuracion:

```
{<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si tienes muy claro como funcionan los *scopes* de Maven, así que te dejo una breve explicación, sacada de [este artículo](https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/introduccion-a-maven):

### Scope (alcance)

El scope sirve para indicar el alcance de nuestra dependencia y su transitividad. Hay 6 tipos:

- **compile**: es la que tenemos por defecto. Indica que la dependencia es necesaria para compilar. La dependencia además se propaga en los proyectos dependientes.
- **provided**: Es como la anterior, *pero esperas que el contenedor ya tenga esa librería*.
- **runtime**: La dependencia es necesaria en tiempo de ejecución pero no es necesaria para compilar.
- **test**: La dependencia es solo para testing.
- **system**: Es como provided pero tienes que incluir la dependencia explícitamente. Maven no buscará este artefacto en tu repositorio local. Habrá que especificar la ruta de la dependencia mediante la etiqueta
- **import**: Se usa en dependencias de tipo *pom* en la sección `<dependencyManagement>`.

### Tu escenario:

- Cuando usas **compile**, maven añade el JAR de la dependencia al generar el ejecutable de tu módulo, porque es una dependencia necesaria que debe estar ahí.
- Cuando usas **provided**, maven usa al compilar el JAR de la dependencia, pero no lo añade porque, como su nombre indica, viene provista por el entorno de ejecución. Por ejemplo, porque has añadido el fichero a la carpeta `/lib` de tu contenedor Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish.

Por tanto, lo lógico sería dejar el scope **compile** para simplificar y automatizar la gestión de esa dependencia.

Comment: Sabes como se usa exatamente: maven-war-plugin y maven-jar-pluguin, creo que la solucion va mas por ahi, ayuda por favor.

Comment: Da igual cómo configures los plug-ins, si la dependencia no la añades a la hora de ejecutar.

Answer (score 0):

Buenos dias/tardes amigos, sigo intentanto con mi problema, eh configurado el pom(jar) con la siguiente configuracion.

[image: Pom maven scope provided jar]

Y este es el pom del proyecto maven donde tiene la dependencia

[image: Pom con dependencia jar]

Y aun no puedo ejecutar el deploy, me sale el siguiente error, no encuentra las clases del modulo maven